# Trying to access the name of the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am trying to access the name of the object (FOI_OMG_101) and extract 101 from the name and   display it in output.field

```
 const dataToInsert = {
 FOI_OMG_101 : {
 name : "jghj.pdf",
 value: "base64"
 }
 };

 const output = {
 field: dataToInsert.substring(8),
 fileName: dataToInsert.FOI_OMG_101.name,
 value: dataToInsert.FOI_OMG_101.value

}
```

Comment: If you can write `dataToInsert.FOI_OMG_101` in the next line, you already *know* the name should be `101`…?!

Comment: `Object.keys(dataToInsert)[0].split('_')[2]` ??

Comment: I want to substring(8) character from  FOI_OMG_101 an display "101" in the output.field

Comment: So it is `Object.keys(dataToInsert)[0].substring(8)` !?

Comment: I repeat though: if you literally hardcode `dataToInsert.FOI_OMG_101` on the next line, then why bend over backwards with `Object.keys(dataToInsert)[0].substring(8)` instead of simply hardcoding `'101'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that accepts a source object and a key and returns the desired target object.

For extracting the number out of the key, you can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the key by `_` and then grab the last item using [`at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at).

```js
function generateOutput(source, key) {
  const desiredKey = Object.keys(source).find((k) => k === key);
  if (!desiredKey) {
    return null;
  }
  return {
    field: desiredKey.split("_").at(-1),
    fileName: source[key].name,
    value: source[key].value,
  };
}

const 
  dataToInsert = { FOI_OMG_101: { name: "jghj.pdf", value: "base64" } },
  key = "FOI_OMG_101";

console.log(generateOutput(dataToInsert, key));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
const dataToInsert = {
  FOI_OMG_101: {
    name: "jghj.pdf",
    value: "base64"
  }
};

const output = Object.entries(dataToInsert).reduce((res, [key, {name, value}]) => ({
    field: key.split('_').pop(),
    fileName: name,
    value
}), {}) 

console.log(output)
```